# Ninject Factory Extension Bind Multiple Concrete Types To One Interface

Tags: c#, .net, inversion-of-control, ninject, factory

### **Introduction:**

I'm using the [Ninject Factory Extension](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.factory/wiki) to inject simple object factories into my service classes.

Here is my interface and two classes that implement it:

```
public interface ICar
{
    void Drive();
    void Stop();
}

public class Mercedes : ICar
{
    public void Drive()
    {
      Do mercedes drive stuff...
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
      Do mercedes stop stuff...  
    }

}

public class Ferrari : ICar
{
    public void Drive()
    {
      Do ferrari drive stuff...
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
      Do ferrari stop stuff...  
    }
}
```

Here is my object factory to dynamically create a car at runtime:

```
public interface ICarFactory
{
   ICar CreateCar(string carType);
}

public class CarFactory : ICarFactory 
{
   public ICar CreateCar(string carType)
   {
       ICar car;

       switch (type)
       {
           case "mercedes":
                car = new Mercedes();
           break;

           case "ferrari":
               car = new Ferrari();
           break;
       }

       return car;
    }
 }
```

Then use ninject factory extension "ToFactory" method to bind my car factory interface:

```
public class CarModule : Ninject.Modules.NinjectModule
{
      public override void Load()
      {
           Bind<ICarFactory>().ToFactory();
      }
}
```

### Problem:

My factory gets injected into my service class as expected and can be used to create
car objects, however ninject blows up here because it cannot properly resolve ICar
to the concrete type ie. `Mercedes` or `Ferrari` returned by the factory `CreateCar()` method.

```
public CarService(string carType, ICarFactory carFactory)
{
   var car = carFactory.CreateCar(carType);
}
```

### Question:

Assuming the factory pattern I'm using here is compatible with how ninject factory extension is intended to work, how do I setup the bindings for ICar -> Ferrari, ICar -> Mercedes etc. so that they may be dynamically resolved at run time with this approach?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not really sure what you expect to happen. Are you expecting that, if the value of `carType` is `"mercedes"`, then the type of `var car` should be `Mercedes` instead of `ICar`? C# doesn't work like this.

Comment: Where are your bindings for `ICar`? The Ninject factories extension is probably taking control here and is looking for your `ICar` bindings. When it doesn't find them it will blow up..

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is an example of custom factory at [`ninject.extension.factory` wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9983226/ninject-factory-custom-instance-provider)

First, create custom implementation of `StandardInstanceProvider` to  override default factory behaviour

```
public class UseFirstArgumentAsNameInstanceProvider : StandardInstanceProvider
{
    protected override string GetName(System.Reflection.MethodInfo methodInfo, object[] arguments)
    {
        return (string)arguments[0];
    }

    protected override ConstructorArgument[] GetConstructorArguments(MethodInfo methodInfo, object[] arguments)
    {
        return base.GetConstructorArguments(methodInfo, arguments).Skip(1).ToArray();
    }
}
```

At `CarModule` specify `UseFirstArgumentAsNameInstanceProvider` (custom instance provider) for `ICarFactory` factory and names for dependencies

```
public class CarModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<ICarFactory>()
            .ToFactory(() => new UseFirstArgumentAsNameInstanceProvider());

        Bind<ICar>()
            .To<Mercedes>()
            .Named("Mercedes");

        Bind<ICar>()
            .To<Ferrari>()
            .Named("Ferrari");
    }
}
```

Resolve factory and dependencies

```
var factory = kernel.Get<ICarFactory>();

var mercedes = factory.CreateCar("Mercedes");
var ferrari = factory.CreateCar("Ferrari");
```

**ps**: here is [full example](https://gist.github.com/4593576)

Comment: Great answer Akim - I implemented this and it works perfectly. Thanks!!

Comment: @Akim Thanks for the feedback, I deleted my answer as this is obviously the right one.  Although could have done without the -1 as my answer would have also worked given the code impl he was using.

Comment: @Gent, trick is to avoid to write implementation of `ICarFactory`, and make `ninject` to implements it according to mapping

Comment: @Akim thanks for this answer - do you have any experience with [Ninject Conventions](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.conventions/wiki) extension, and how you would write the `ICar` bindings using that way instead? I posted a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15868820/533958) building off this answer - would appreciate any guidance.

Comment: Hey @Akim, How would you bind to a default car if no name matches. Like --  Bind<ICar>().To<DefaultCar>();