# Using Ninject custom instance providers to bind successfully using factory method argument to resolve

Tags: ninject-extensions, abstract-factory, open-generics, ninject-conventions

I've been studying [this accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14456264/533958) to a similar question in which what I believe is a concrete factory returns an implementation based on a string argument on the factory method matching a named binding on the concrete implementation.

I'm struggling to get a slightly more complex example to work properly when the factory is an abstract factory, and I wish to use Ninject convention-based binding.  Consider the following test:

```cs
[Fact]
public void VehicleBuilderFactory_Creates_Correct_Builder_For_Specified_Client()
{
    // arrange
    StandardKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();
    kernel.Bind(typeof (IVehicleBuilderFactory<,>))
        .ToFactory(() => new UseFirstArgumentAsNameInstanceProvider())
        .InSingletonScope();

    kernel.Bind(scanner => scanner
                    .FromThisAssembly()
                    .SelectAllClasses()
                    .WhichAreNotGeneric()
                    .InheritedFrom(typeof(IVehicleBuilder<>))
                    .BindAllInterfaces());

    var bicycleBuilderFactory = 
        kernel.Get<IVehicleBuilderFactory<IVehicleBuilder<BlueBicycle>, BlueBicycle>>();
    string country = "Germany";
    string localizedColor = "blau";

    // act
    var builder = bicycleBuilderFactory.Create<IVehicleBuilder<BlueBicycle>>(country);
    Bicycle Bicycle = builder.Build(localizedColor);

    // assert
    Assert.IsType<BlueBicycleBuilder_Germany>(builder);
    Assert.IsType<BlueBicycle>(Bicycle);
    Assert.Equal(localizedColor, Bicycle.Color);
}
```

Here's where I try juggling with torches & knives 'cause I saw it on the internet once:

```cs
public class UseFirstArgumentAsNameInstanceProvider : StandardInstanceProvider
{
    protected override string GetName(MethodInfo methodInfo, object[] arguments) {
        return methodInfo.GetGenericArguments()[0].Name + "Builder_" + (string)arguments[0];
        // ex: Germany -> 'BlueBicycle' + 'Builder_' + 'Germany' = 'BlueBicyleBuilder_Germany'
    }

    protected override ConstructorArgument[] GetConstructorArguments(MethodInfo methodInfo, object[] arguments) {
        return base.GetConstructorArguments(methodInfo, arguments).Skip(1).ToArray();
    }
}
```

I get stabbed and set ablaze when I try to assign `bicycleBuilderFactory` with this error:

```cs
System.InvalidCastException was unhandled by user code
  Message=Unable to cast object of type 'Castle.Proxies.ObjectProxy' to type 'Ninject.Extensions.Conventions.Tests.IVehicleBuilderFactory`2[Ninject.Extensions.Conventions.Tests.IVehicleBuilder`1[Ninject.Extensions.Conventions.Tests.BlueBicycle],Ninject.Extensions.Conventions.Tests.BlueBicycle]'.
  Source=System.Core
  StackTrace:
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.<CastIterator>d__b1`1.MoveNext()
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
       at Ninject.ResolutionExtensions.Get[T](IResolutionRoot root, IParameter[] parameters) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Syntax\ResolutionExtensions.cs:line 37
       at Ninject.Extensions.Conventions.Tests.NinjectFactoryConventionsTests.VehicleBuilderFactory_Creates_Correct_Builder_For_Specified_Client() in C:\Programming\Ninject.Extensions.Conventions.Tests\NinjectFactoryConventionsTests.cs:line 40
  InnerException:
```

***Is it possible to bind using the*** `ToFactory()` **method and custom provider, using the factory method argument** (`"Germany"`) **along with the generic type argument** (`IVehicleBiulder<BlueBicycle>, BlueBicycle`) **to resolve the type?**

Here's the rest of the code for the test, as compact and readable as I could make it.

```cs
public interface IVehicleBuilderFactory<T, TVehicle> 
    where T : IVehicleBuilder<TVehicle> where TVehicle : IVehicle
{
    T Create<T>(string country);
}
```

**VehicleBuilder implementations**

```cs
public interface IVehicleBuilder<T> where T : IVehicle { T Build(string localizedColor); }

abstract class BicycleBuilder<T> : IVehicleBuilder<T> where T : Bicycle
{
    public abstract T Build(string localizedColor);
}

public abstract class RedBicycleBuilder : IVehicleBuilder<RedBicycle>
{
    private readonly RedBicycle _Bicycle;
    public RedBicycleBuilder(RedBicycle Bicycle) { _Bicycle = Bicycle; }
    public RedBicycle Build(string localizedColor)
    {
        _Bicycle.Color = localizedColor;
        return _Bicycle;
    }
}
public abstract class GreenBicycleBuilder : IVehicleBuilder<GreenBicycle>
{
    private readonly GreenBicycle _Bicycle;
    public GreenBicycleBuilder(GreenBicycle Bicycle) { _Bicycle = Bicycle; }
    public GreenBicycle Build(string localizedColor)
    {
        _Bicycle.Color = localizedColor;
        return _Bicycle;
    }
}
public abstract class BlueBicycleBuilder : IVehicleBuilder<BlueBicycle>
{
    private readonly BlueBicycle _Bicycle;
    public BlueBicycleBuilder(BlueBicycle Bicycle) { _Bicycle = Bicycle; }
    public BlueBicycle Build(string localizedColor)
    {
        _Bicycle.Color = localizedColor;
        return _Bicycle;
    }
}

public class RedBicycleBuilder_USA : RedBicycleBuilder {
    public RedBicycleBuilder_USA(RedBicycle Bicycle) : base(Bicycle) { }
}

public class RedBicycleBuilder_Germany : RedBicycleBuilder {
    public RedBicycleBuilder_Germany(RedBicycle Bicycle) : base(Bicycle) { }
}
public class RedBicycleBuilder_France : RedBicycleBuilder {
    public RedBicycleBuilder_France(RedBicycle Bicycle) : base(Bicycle) { }
}
public class RedBicycleBuilder_Default : RedBicycleBuilder {
    public RedBicycleBuilder_Default(RedBicycle Bicycle) : base(Bicycle) { }
}

public class GreenBicycleBuilder_USA : GreenBicycleBuilder {
    public GreenBicycleBuilder_USA(GreenBicycle Bicycle) : base(Bicycle) { }
}
public class GreenBicycleBuilder_Germany : GreenBicycleBuilder {
    public GreenBicycleBuilder_Germany(GreenBicycle Bicycle) : base(Bicycle) { }
}
public class GreenBicycleBuilder_France : GreenBicycleBuilder {
    public GreenBicycleBuilder_France(GreenBicycle Bicycle) : base(Bicycle) { }
}
public class GreenBicycleBuilder_Default : GreenBicycleBuilder {
    public GreenBicycleBuilder_Default(GreenBicycle Bicycle) : base(Bicycle) { }
}

public class BlueBicycleBuilder_USA : BlueBicycleBuilder
{
    public BlueBicycleBuilder_USA(BlueBicycle Bicycle) : base(Bicycle) { }
}
public class BlueBicycleBuilder_Germany : BlueBicycleBuilder {
    public BlueBicycleBuilder_Germany(BlueBicycle Bicycle) : base(Bicycle) { }
}
public class BlueBicycleBuilder_France : BlueBicycleBuilder
{
    public BlueBicycleBuilder_France(BlueBicycle Bicycle) : base(Bicycle) { }
}
public class BlueBicycleBuilder_Default : BlueBicycleBuilder
{
    public BlueBicycleBuilder_Default(BlueBicycle Bicycle) : base(Bicycle) { }
}
```

**Vehicle implementations:**

```cs
public interface IVehicle { string Color { get; set; } }
public abstract class Vehicle : IVehicle { public string Color { get; set; } }
public abstract class Bicycle : Vehicle { }
public class RedBicycle : Bicycle { }
public class GreenBicycle : Bicycle { }
public class BlueBicycle : Bicycle { }
```

Comment: Shouldn't a bicycle have a colour and a location rather than that information be contained in the type? Then you just need a bicycle factory whose create method takes a colour and a country?

Comment: @LukeN well, that's probably where my simplifying abstraction falls down. The colors are meant to abstract the fact that, for example, `RedBicycle` (which could inherit from something like `Bicycle<Red>`) has many other unique behaviors or characteristics other than its color. Furthermore, if it's a `RedBicyle` for *Germany*, its behavior would be altered (horn sounds like 'Achtung!' or something). I'll try to think of a better simplifying abstraction and refactor this question...

Comment: Have a look at http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_component_system. Using deep class hierarchies gets really tricky as they grow.

Comment: @LukeN +1 for the link; I've studied the [observer](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern), [visitor](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern), and [strategy](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) patterns (more since posting this question), but hadn't heard of of *Entity Component System* as a concept. Let me post a proposed redesign of the `Bicycle` system and see if this might make my issue go away.

Answer (score 1):

Based on comments from @LukeN, I've refactored the `Bicycle` class, so that its color is set through constructor injection with an `IColorSetter`. The `IColorSetter` implementation has a generic `Color` type, and each of the `Color` implementations are 'localized' by way of constructor injection with an `IColorLocalizer<T>`.

This way, no class seems to have knowledge of anything beyond what is logically its responsibility (I think).

However, I'll need to think about this more to see how the refactored classes shown below can be used to show how to use a Ninject custom instance provider could be used to pick the property `IColorLocalizer<T>` now, since it's the only class that will know about colors and languages; the color coming from its generic type, and the language coming from the name of the implementation itself.

Since asking the original post, I've moved away from using an IoC container to make choices like this, choosing instead to programmatically put in code a switch for picking an implementation, with a default implementation selected for any unhandled outlier cases. But I'm not sure if it's mainly to get beyond something that's stumped me, or because it's a poor choice to lean on an IoC container in this way.

I'll need to update this answer more as I think about it.

**Vehicles**

```cs
public abstract class Vehicle {
    public abstract string Color { get; internal set; }
    public abstract string Move();
}

public class Bicycle : Vehicle {
    public Bicycle(IColorSetter colorSetter) { colorSetter.SetColor(this); }
    public override string Color { get; internal set; }
    public override string Move() { return "Pedaling!"; }
}
```

**Color setters**

```cs
public interface IColorSetter { void SetColor(Vehicle vehicle); }

public class ColorSetter<T> : IColorSetter where T : Color
{
    private readonly T _color;
    public ColorSetter(T color) { _color = color; }

    public void SetColor(Vehicle vehicle) { vehicle.Color = _color.Name; }
}
```

**Color localizers**

```cs
public interface IColorLocalizer<in T> where T : Color {
    void LocalizeColor(T color);
}

public class GermanBlueLocalizer : IColorLocalizer<Blue> {
    public void LocalizeColor(Blue color) { color.Name = "blau"; }
}

public class EnglishBlueLocalizer : IColorLocalizer<Blue> {
    public void LocalizeColor(Blue color) { color.Name = "blue"; }
}
```

**Colors**

```cs
public abstract class Color { public string Name { get; internal set; } }

public class Red : Color {
    public Red(IColorLocalizer<Red> colorLocalizer) {
        colorLocalizer.LocalizeColor(this); }
}

public class Green : Color {
    public Green(IColorLocalizer<Green> colorLocalizer) {
        colorLocalizer.LocalizeColor(this); }
}

public class Blue : Color {
    public Blue(IColorLocalizer<Blue> colorLocalizer) {
        colorLocalizer.LocalizeColor(this); }
}
```

Comment: Why would a colorsetter need to know about a vehicle? You want your bicycle to have a colour and a language. So you want to be able to create a bicycle by going BicycleFactory.Create(Colour c, Language l), or just by setting properties after you create a bike. The bicycle class probably doesn't need to know the name of it's colour in the specified language though, some other class who is using the bicycle class does. In which case, inject the dependency into that class.

Comment: Then the next problem is that you have a matrix consisting of colours in one dimension and languages in the next. If you try to build a type for each one, you end up with an explosion of types when you add new language or colour. You can hide the implementation of the colour name resolver behind an interface that takes a colour and a language, which then lets you create the class as a matrix, or a join table, or a series of lists, or behind an ioc trick. Which let's you avoid the combinatorial explosion that happens when you add a third property to the bike.

Comment: Say you add Mountain and Road bikes. The colour and the type definitely have nothing to do with each other. If you follow the scheme you proposed above, you end up with a GermanRedMountainBike and a GermanRedRacingBike and so on. If red german bikes get a +2% to downhill speed, then you have to push that and all other rules into the the different types. But then you need have a difference between a GermanRed21SpeedRacingBike and a GermanRed18SpeedRacing bike! It gets very difficult to maintain very quickly. Does that make any sense?

Comment: @LukeN All great points that you've made. Standby for an edit to this answer incorporating your suggestions. The point you make about creating an `IColorNameResolver` that takes a color and a language may help guide the example back towards my original question about leveraging IoC containers for this resolving problem.